# Why does qemu work with chroot, but not with systemd-nspawn?

Tags: qemu

Here's how I installed qemu/the system:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu qemu-user qemu-user-static binfmt-support debootstrap binutils systemd-nspawn systemd-container #All deps
debootstrap --foreign --arch=i386 sttretch ./x86/ http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian
#I installed a more recent version of qemu-user-static(4.0.95 as the file says) and rewrote the files
sudo chroot ./x86/ /debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage
```

When I do:

```
#mount /proc /sys /dev /dev/pts /dev/shm
sudo chroot ./x86/ /bin/su -l root
```

it logs in atomatically, but when I try with systemd-nspawn it outputs the following:

```
Spawning container x86 on /home/pi/x86.
Press ^] three times within 1s to kill container.
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
```

And it hangs like that.

EDIT: I tried both -D and -b -D(Output is the same)

Is it because of depedency problems, wrong qemu version or something else?

Comment: I'm not very good in English. Sorry for that.

Comment: Uh, qemu is 4.1.0rc5

Comment: I will try with qemu-4.2.0